# storing data in session in USSD java application.

Tags: java, session, ussd

I am developing a ussd application and i want to store some info in session was wondering how to do that considering in ussd a http request first goes to the mobile telco who have provided the gateway then to my server hence there is no session between the client device and my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to store the info in coherence. since i was using weblogic and it comes with coherence data grid. I just created a coherence cluster within weblogic and configured my application by including the following files in my application in the resources folder cache-config.xml and tangosol-coherence-override.xml. And I was set.